# How to find elements in a drop-down menu wrapped inside <li>, <a> and >ul> tags in Selenium Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm new to Selenium and needs help with finding the xpath of particular tag to get it clicked.

I want to click *SOQL Query* link from the highlighted drop-down menu as given in below image:

[image]

This is the code what i have tried so far :

```
//hovering

 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

 //First click on dropdown down to open options
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li.top > a.top_link"))).click();

//Now select opened option
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("a[href*='query.php']"))).click();
```

Comment: in the second expectedcondition, need to use css instead of linkedtext

Answer (score 0):

Use the Action class to handle such menu click

```
WebElement queriesLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.top > a.top_link"));

WebElement soqlQueryLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[contains(.,'SOQL Query')]"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(queriesLink ).clickAndHold(soqlQueryLink ).click().build().perform();
```